# window.location.href in vscode webview api

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, javascript-objects, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I'm developing a vscode webview extension. I'm loading an external javascript file. In that file, there's a line as follows:

```
var _origin = extractOrigin(window.location.href)

function extractOrigin(url){
    return <regex>.exec(url)[1] || null;
}
```

I'm getting the following error,

```
Cannot read property 1 of null
```

This is because `window.location.href` is null.

What's the equivalent of the `window` object functions in vscode i.e
`window.location.href` equivalent should give the current url of page loaded?

Comment: What is inside `window.location`?

Comment: @Anton VSCode renders the html via webview. javscript can also be included. So, in my js file I have `window.location.href`. On a normal browser it gives out the current url but in vscode it's giving null

Comment: Yes, you have this information in your question. I'm wondering what is inside `window.location` (because `window.location.href` is null for you, so `window.location` seems to be an object, right?)